# What is wrong with my boot process

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I haven't used my desktop in a while and installed the most recent version of Ubuntu (18.04.1) but something has gone wrong with grub.

I have a SSD with dual boot - 378GB is for windows (sdb2) and 81GB is for linux (sdb6), the current OS I am using.

I also have my old 2TB HDD which now serves as storage space - that has a 1.3TB Windows partition (sda1) and a 500G Linux partition (sda3) which I will eventually get round to merging together.

When I boot, I am greeted with the grub command line. However, when I type `exit` it redirects me to the correct grub boot menu?

I do not understand what all the different sdb partitions are and what they are used for?

Grub command line capture:
[image: Grub command line capture]

Grub boot menu capture:
[image: Grub boot menu capture]

I used the boot info script and have put the results below. Apologies for dumping the entire text but I am not sure which part is useful and which isn't.

EDIT: [Boot info results](https://pastebin.com/K4D3w40b)

Comment: Sounds like your boot-order in BIOS is wrong. Check the boot-order in your BIOS. The boot-inf summary shows obsolete instance of Grub installed in MBR of both drives. Did you run the recommended repair? The boot-info summary is not complete due to limits of question length, better to use pastebin an provide link.

Comment: @mook765 I checked and my the BIOS is definitely looking at the SSD as the first boot. I've put the boot info results in Pastebin now FYI

Comment: boot-info-summary is not complete again, missing the end. From what I see so far you should run boot-repair again and choose the recommended repair option, that should do it.

Comment: @mook765 I ran the boot-repair script and it worked, thanks! The results are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cWmcTXWkSV/) if you are interested